# Multi plot on a data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm asking you my question here because after a long time on the internet, I didn't found anything.
Here's the problem:
I'm working on a data science project and I want to put some results on a plot.

I have a data frame which is group by 2 attributes (as you can see on the picture). Those two attributes are "id_campaign" and "dayofweek", and all I want is to put on the same graph in order to see if there is any trend. 
I have enough reputation points to put a picture now :D!

So here is my data frame, you will understand more easily i think

[image: my df]

Comment: (as you can see on the picture) ... what picture? I see no picture

Comment: hi Andersson, the picture is missing cause i don't have enough reputation to put it...
I need at least a 10 pt reputation

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what you are trying to do w/o an example.  Here are some plots I use when looked at "grouped by" data:

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Bar plot of average of column_c by column_a

```
df.groupby('column_a').column_c.mean().plot(kind='bar')
plt.ylabel('Average of Column C Per Column A')
```

Bar plot of total of column_c by column_a

```
df.groupby('column_a').column_c.sum().plot(kind='bar')
plt.ylabel('Total of Column C Per Column A')
```

Grouped histograms (shows the distribution for each group)

```
df.column_c.hist(by=df.column_a)
df.column_c.hist(by=df.column_a, sharex=True)  # common X axis
df.column_c.hist(by=df.column_a, sharex=True, sharey=True)  # common X and Y axis
```

Boxplot of column_c by column_a (shows five-number summary and outliers)

```
df.boxplot(column='column_c', by='column_a')
```

Scatterplot matrix of all numerical columns

```
pd.scatter_matrix(df)
```

Scatterplot matrix of specific numerical columns

```
pd.scatter_matrix(df[['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']])
```